# How to load data if delimiter is escaped?

Tags: mariadb, escaping, mysql-workbench, delimiter

I have following issue loading a `.txt` file into my mariadb.
The data in the file is separated with pipe `|` as the delimiter.
However, in one data instance, I'm facing following issue:

`|number|text \|||`
Now, because of the backslash, it considers the delimiter as part of the text instead of as a delimiter. This causes the rest of the columns to be shifted to the left by one.

I tried to handle this when loading the file with following way:

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "some path"
INTO TABLE Table_Name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY ''
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@Column1
...
,@Column34
...
,@Column85)
SET
...
ColumnName = if(@Column34 = '', null, REPLACE(@Column34, '\\', ''))
...
```

This didn't work - I also tried to replace `\\|` with empty string which also failed. When fetching the data after loading it and looking into that particular field, I always have: `some text |`

Note: I cannot change source data

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: I'm using mariadb as underlying database and the sql above is supposed to be executed in MySQL Workbench

Comment: I'm assuming that at that point where I do the replacement, I'm already too late. Is there a way to tell mysql before reading data to ignore escape characters or that delimiter is not allowed to be escaped etc.?